# Hide/Show CKEditor buttons on an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am developing a simple tool for sending emails.

I am using CKEditor for my textarea formatting.

I want a scenario, whereby by default whereby the formatting buttons do not show till the user clicks on "Show Formatting buttons"

How can I achieve this with CKEditor without using two textareas.

Comment: can you please explain what you have attempted to this point, and where in your logic you having issues with this?

Comment: What I have now is: I have two textareas, one plain text, the other CKEditor richtext, by default, I show plain text, when user click on link to show formatting buttons, I hide plain text and show CK richtext. I am looking for a cleaner execution (for a smooth transition) or maybe if such is inbuilt in CK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link as an example:

[Create and destroy CKEditor instances on the fly](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/6593/_samples/ajax.html)

In the example they use a `div`, but you can just as easily use a standard `textarea`, and it will do the plain text / rich text tradeoff you are looking for.